# moodle transfering to another PC error

Tags: database, postgresql, xampp, moodle, database-restore

I'm trying to restore my moodle site to another pc. first of all I backed up my pgsql database and copied my moodledata file and moodle file. Then installed Xampp and Postgresql to the transferring pc and past the moodle file in hddocs of xampp. then installed moodle databases by installing moodle. then replace the other files in respective places and restored the previous database.
then when I run the URL in the address bar an error massage is displayed as shown below:

```
Error: Database connection failed
It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.
The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in the **config.php**
```

Comment: Did you read the error message? Becasue it is pretty clear that your database is not running or is configured wrong

Comment: Have you updated the database details in config.php to match the local copy of your database?

Comment: thank you @MechMK1  for helping. it worked. the problem was with the passwords.

Comment: thank you @davosmith for helping. it worked. the problem was with the passwords.